# Type error in labelFunc in KeyBoardDatePicker component, Material-ui/pickers, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this material-ui pickers component:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
   value={selectedDate}
   onChange={(_, newValue) => handleClick(newValue)}
   labelFunc={renderLabel}
   disableToolbar
   variant='inline'
   inputVariant='filled'
   format='YYYYMMDD'
   autoOk
 />
```

Where renderLabel function is:

```
const renderLabel = (date: string | null) => date === null ? 'placeholder' : momen(date).format(YYYYMMDD)string
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Type '(date: string | null) => string' is not assignable to type '(date: MaterialUiPickersDate, invalidLabel: string) => string'.
 Types of parameters 'date' and 'date' are incompatible.
   Type 'MaterialUiPickersDate' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
     Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I also tried importing Moment instead and use it like this:

```
const renderLabel = (date: Moment) => date === null ? 'placeholder' : momen(date).format(YYYYMMDD)string
```

It still gives compiler error.
What type should I be using for labelFunc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly fine with pure `Date`:

```
renderLabel: (date: Date|null, invalidLabel: string) => string
```

Full example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers'

type MyComponentProps = {
    selectedDate: string;
    renderLabel: (date: Date|null, invalidLabel: string) => string
    handleClick: (v: string | null | undefined) => null
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ selectedDate, renderLabel, handleClick }) => (<KeyboardDatePicker
    value={selectedDate}
    onChange={(_, newValue) => handleClick(newValue)}
    labelFunc={renderLabel}
    disableToolbar
    variant='inline'
    inputVariant='filled'
    format='YYYYMMDD'
    autoOk
/>
)

export default MyComponent;
```

Tested with

```
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
```

**Updated Date with null, thanks @known-as-bmf!**

Comment: With your solution I still get this error: 
Type '(date: Date, invalidLabel: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(date: MaterialUiPickersDate, invalidLabel: string) => string'.
 Types of parameters 'date' and 'date' are incompatible.
   Type 'MaterialUiPickersDate' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
     Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date'.ts

Comment: Did you try to build or it's IDE complain? What version are you using?

Comment: You probably have to type it `Date | null`

Comment: @known-as-bmf maybe you are right, but it works even in this form (at least for me :))

Comment: It may have something to do with tsconfig and null strictness in your project 

Comment: @known-as-bmf should be, ```MaterialUiPickersDate = DateType | null``` gives a hint for that :)

Comment: These versions: 
"@date-io/moment": "1.3.13",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
"moment": "^2.27.0",

Comment: My version of the pickers. Check please updated version with ``` (date: Date|null, invalidLabel: string) => string```

Comment: You were right about the null part. I used `Moment | null` and it worked while using `Moment` on its own didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.

The component wants to give you a `MaterialUiPickersDate` and you function accepts a `string`. They don't match.

Change your function to accept a `MaterialUiPickersDate` and it will not complain anymore.

Comment: MaterialUiPickersDate is an internal thing and is not supposed to be used as type. Instead the documentation says to use type from the adaptor, like Moment. I tried Moment but I still get an error.

Comment: @AleksandraS the function should accept 'Moment | null' just solved this problem using exactly this advice.